# Password checker Java

Tags: java

Write a function to return if the string is a valid password.

It must be at least 8 characters long and may only consist 
of letters and digits.

This is my code so far:

```
for (int i = 1; i < password.length() -1; i++)
{
     char l = password.charAt(i);
     if (password.length() < 8 && !Character.isLetter(l) || !Character.isDigit(l))
     {
        return false;
     }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Why start `i` at 1?  You'll miss the first letter, at index 0.

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: You do not need to repeatedly check the length inside your loop. You need to have `! isLetter && ! isDigit` (notice **and**) .

Comment: Also, you tagged this both Java and JavaScript.  Java and JavaScript are not at all the same thing.  This is Java.

Comment: General advice is that it's bad for security to use `String` for passwords; use `char[]` array instead. But for a programming exercise it's ok.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou It would be nice to provide a link explaining *why* it is a general advice so everybody can learn about it.

Comment: @MarkusBenko good point. The Javadoc for [java.io.Console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) explains you should use `readPassword()` and then zero out the chars as soon as possible to prevent keeping the password in memory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static boolean isValid(String pw) {
    return pw.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}");
}
```

Comment: `\w` matches letters, digits and underscore.

Comment: ah yeah good point, changed to be more strict

Comment: That's correct. Alternative: `"\p{Alnum}{8,}"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to do this

```
private static boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    return password.matches("(\\w+){8,}");
}
```